# Email Reading in Java by keeping the text positions

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read emails using Java. I got the in-box mails correctly.
But the problem is text body is shown in line by line. I need the body text as it is shown in mail,ie output text should be in same order (rephrasing proposal: "tabular alignment") as shown in mail.

This is the code I used to get body text from Message object,

```
private static String getTextFromMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException
{
    String result = "";
    if (message.isMimeType("text/plain"))
    {
        result = message.getContent().toString();
    }
    else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
    {
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
        result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws MessagingException, IOException
{
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain"))
        {
            result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
            break;
        }
        else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html"))
        {
            String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
            result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        }
        else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart)
        {
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart) bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For example, this is the mail content:
[image].

I need output as,

```
Beschreibung     Stückpreis   Anzahl            Betrag  
  22545047     106,56 EUR       1        €106,56 EUR
```

as it as shown in mail.

But I got the output,

```
Beschreibung



Stückpreis



Anzahl



Betrag

22545047



106,56 EUR



1



€106,56 EUR
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

By the way, the strange words are German for "description", "price per piece", "number of pieces", "total price for this kind". I.e. they form a bill and are irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: Please show examples of your output and the different desired output.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Question updated. Please check the output I am expecting and Image I attached

Comment: " should be in same order" I do not see an ordering difference.

Comment: What happens if you replace `result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();` by `result = result + bodyPart.getContent();`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact position of all newlines? The formatting you chose hides them. Bold is probably not a helpful formatting choice. Formatting as code is probably better. For that make sure that all lines of the output start with four blanks/spaces/Leerzeichen/" ".

Comment: If 10 spaces are between the word "Beschreibung" and "Stückpreis", then the output also should contain that space. That I need. I mean keep the spaces between words

Comment: result = result + bodyPart.getContent(); displays all mail content in a single line without keeping the spaces between the words

Comment: You really need to learn about StackOverflow formatting options to get that across. Changing the phrasing of your explanation of what you want is probably also required.

Comment: For debugging please change the occurrences of "\n" to "1\n", "2\n", "3\n". That will allow to tell which part of your code eats the spaces. I guess it is the "parse(html)" part.

Comment: Please demonstrate your actual problem by showing the output when not inserting newlines. Make sure to use a formatting which keeps the (missing) whitespaces. Make sure that the output actually looks here on StackOverflow like you see it yourself.

Comment: Please make especially sure that the desired output you show is actually looking here like what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Yunnosch : Thank you so much for editing the question as I expected

Comment: I am confident that I now understood your goal. I have extended my answer to cover the second problem, even if in a negative way. I edited your question with a proposal of how to get your actual problem across. Feel free to undo my changes and edit to clarify your intend. Otherwise I assume that you agree.

Comment: The syntax highlighting coloring is a little distracting, I admit. I invite any other SO user to improve the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not like the newlines which you explicitly insert in some of your "rendering" methods.

In order to get rid of them, delete all occurrences of

```
+ "\n"
```

in your code.

Then consider adding a single `+ "\n"` at the end of the output.

In case the text your are outputting is the result of a html->plain text conversion, you lose the tabular alignment created by the html rendering. There are no "ten spaces". In order to get the alignment information translated into ascii-art (spaces to align columns) you'd have to do some intense analysis of the html markup and derive an appropriate number of spaces to insert.